# JavaScript Promise Setup

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise

I am pretty experienced engineer, but Promises in JavaScript are still super confusing to me. On top of it, project I am on uses Flow to type JavaScript.

So, I have a function A that returns a list of URLs that are returned from a network request. This function actually returns a promise and it is async. (Return type is `Promise<Array<URL>>`)

Now, I need to add another request that also returns a list of URLs. Same deal as before, let's call it function B. (Same return type `Promise<Array<URL>>`).

Then the caller of the original function expects a single promise to be returned. So, I was thinking of making a function C, that first calls function B, then based on the outcome of the function B, it will either return that promise or call function A and return it's promise.

I have to keep it all async and for the life of me I cannot figure this out. How do I write function C?

Please halp! I hope this makes sense.

P.S.
Kinda like this:

```
async getAllURLs(): Promise<?Array<SignedURL>> 
{

  let result: Promise<?Array<SignedURL>> = Promise.resolve([]); // wrong

  let res1 = this.getBetterUrls().then((urls) => 
  {
    if (urls && urls.length > 0) 
    {
      result = res1;
    } 
    else 
    {
      let res2 = this.getOldUrls().then((lesserUrls) => 
      {
        if (lesserUrls && lesserUrls.length > 0) 
        {
          result = res2;
        }
      });
    }
  });

  return result; // wrong
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I imagine this would do the trick:

```
async getAllURLs(): Promise<Array<SignedURL>> {
  const betterUrls = await this.getBetterUrls();

  if (betterUrls && betterUrls.length > 0) { return betterUrls; }

  const lesserUrls = await this.getOldUrls();

  return lesserUrls && lesserUrls.length > 0 ? lesserUrls : [];
}
```

Comment: wouldn't this make it not a sync?

Comment: No, this is exactly how `async`/`await` is used to write async code.

Comment: `async getAllURLs` ... @SpaceBear - the clue is in the word `async` ... definitely asynchronous

Comment: because the caller is not doing await?

Comment: `await ...` uses promises internally afaik, so you don't have to manually create it. When you call the `async` function you get a promise that is used to track the return of your function.

Comment: @SpaceBear As far as the caller is concerned, it will be receiving a Promise from this function and it can do with that what it will. `async` automatically wraps all of the function's return values (and thrown exceptions) in a Promise.